# Is there a way to add an alert to Airflow UI from within a Task?

Tags: airflow

Essentially what i want to do is to perform some validation on the dag list and display alerts in the UI if there are issues. Examples being an alert if any DAGs got created with a None schedule, or an alert if any DAGs are paused. I found [these docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/customize-ui.html#add-custom-alert-messages-on-the-dashboard) that talk about how to add an alert at build, but I am hoping there is some way to do it dynamically.

Comment: You can not (at least not out of the box) but rather than alerting you should think about preventing.  For the case of preventing you have things you can do such as raising exceptions (prevent deployment of DAG with no schedule) or prevent ability to click on pause button from specific roles.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I like the idea of raising the error in the DAG file. I will have to see if i can make it work with our set up as we use a DAG factory so i would have to handle the error in such a way that it doesn't halt the processing of the rest of the DAGs.
As far as the role idea, its not an access concern, its more of a fail safe as we do turn DAGs off from time to time and they don't always end up turned back on at the end of the day.

Comment: I was refering more to unit test that raises error as part of the CI checks before deploying dag to production

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, that won't work for our use case. We use a DAG factory and it uses a Variable in Airflow to map out the DAGs so it won't be until its deployed that the system will even know if one of the generated DAGs has a schedule or not.

Comment: Just bouncing an idea, although not sure if it works, you might want to check if writing a custom Airflow plugin that could flash messages can work in your case. 
References on writing custom plugins:
https://github.com/astronomer/astro-provider-databricks/blob/main/src/astro_databricks/plugins/plugin.py  

https://medium.com/swlh/airflow-custom-plugins-38f0848b74c5  


https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/plugins.html